# What's the way to simulate success after SIGSEGV

Tags: c, signals, memory-mapping

I'm capturing a `SIGSEGV` on a read/write to a known block of memory. The block is mmaped and under my control, so it can be manipulated. I'd like to simulate the read/write succeeding, actually process the data and continue the application. I've got two possible solutions, but they all seem too complicated. I'm hoping there's a better way to achieve this:

1. Borrow the trick from debuggers and:

   - mmap the area and protect
   - wait for `SIGSEGV`
   - get the read/write size from instruction type
   - for reads, put the required data in memory and remove protection
   - single-step the app
   - for writes, read what was written and process
   - in the single-step `TRAP` protect the page again and continue the app
2. Do some crazy processing on the instruction itself and:

   - mmap the area and protect
   - wait for `SIGSEGV`
   - get the instruction under `eip` and simulate its effects
   - return after the instruction

The app is not running under root account, in case that matters.

I'm assuming x86_64 and don't really care about other platforms at the moment.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233464/can-a-c-program-continue-execution-after-a-signal-is-handled

Comment: Seems like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663456/write-a-signal-handler-to-catch-sigsegv -- or if not, could you please explain why this isn't a duplicate?