# What does REG_* in ucontext.h

Tags: c, linux, glossary

here is code, I don't know what each detain meaning for them, for example, REG_RIP, what is "RIP"

```
//ucontext.h
enum
{
//...
  REG_RIP,
//...
}
```

[here](https://gist.github.com/roroco/0650f7189476b74b58ba) is full code

Answer (score 1):

It's the name of a register.  REG_RIP means "register RIP" and RIP is the Instruction Pointer.  So that enum value is a "name" for the instruction pointer (aka program counter) register on x86.

Comment: Is there doc for ucontext.h, I doesn't find it, even you have explain it, I don't know how to use it, I see this in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233464/can-a-c-program-continue-execution-after-a-signal-is-handled/30169485#30169485)

Comment: @anxvonial: here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ucontext.h.html

Comment: I don't find the REG_* explaination

Comment: @anxvonial: the REG_* explanation is in my answer.  You wanted an answer, right?